# Testing for 2 arrays that have duplicates. cant get the last test to come back pass

Tags: javascript

Attempting to get the below code to pass the test at the bottom. I believe my issue is inside the registerStudent()

I am supposed to do the following:

> In this task, you will add the method `registerStudent()` to the `Bootcamp` class.
> This method should have a single parameter called `studentToRegister`. This parameter will take an object created from the `Student` class as its argument.
> In the method body, if the `studentToRegister` argument does not possess either a name and a email property, `console.log()` the string 'Invalid name or email' then return the Boolean value of false.
> Otherwise, iterate through the `this.students` array to check for if any of the students in that array have the same email as the `studentToRegister`. Compare the email of each student in the this.students array to the email of the studentToRegister.
> There are multiple potential ways to check this, including the `for ... of` loop method you learned last week.
> If you want to take on a challenge, you could try researching how to use the array method called `find()`, which we have not yet covered.
> In the case that a matching email is found, `console.log()` a string that says that email is already registered, then return false.
> Otherwise:
> Use the array method `push()` to add the `studentToRegister` object to the `this.students` array.
> `console.log()` a message indicating success, using the `studentToRegister`'s name and the `bootcamp`'s name in the message.
> return the Boolean value of true.

```js
class Student {
    constructor(name, email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
}

class Bootcamp {
    constructor(name, level, students = []) {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
        this.students = students;
    }
    registerStudent(studentToRegister = Student) {
        function studentToRegister(Student); {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.students; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < studentToRegister.length; j++) {
                    if (this.students[i] == studentToRegister[j]) {
                        console.log('That email is already registered')
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        this.students.push(studentToRegister); {
                            console.log(`${studentToRegister} is now registered`)
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
testStudent = new Student('Bugs Bunny', 'bugs@bunny.com');
console.log(testStudent);
if (testStudent.name === 'Bugs Bunny' && testStudent.email === 'bugs@bunny.com') {
    console.log('TASK 1: PASS');
};



reactBootcamp = new Bootcamp("React", "Advanced");
console.log(reactBootcamp);
if (reactBootcamp.name === 'React' && reactBootcamp.level === 'Advanced'
    && Array.isArray(reactBootcamp.students) && reactBootcamp.students.length === 0) {
    console.log('TASK 2: PASS');
}

const runTest = (bootcamp, student) => {
    const attemptOne = bootcamp.registerStudent(student);
    const attemptTwo = bootcamp.registerStudent(student);
    const attemptThree = bootcamp.registerStudent(new Student("Babs Bunny"));
    if ( attemptOne && !attemptTwo && !attemptThree) {
        console.log("TASK 3: PASS");
    }
};

runTest(reactBootcamp, testStudent);
```

Comment: You have a syntax error, the extra `;` in `function studentToRegister(Student); {`

Comment: `studentToRegister` shouldn't be a function, it's suposed to be the name of the parameter to `registerStudent`. And it's not array, so I don't know why you're trying to use `studentToRegister.length`.

Answer (score 1):

`studentToRegister` is not an array, you shouldn't loop over it.

You also shouldn't try to define it as a function, it's just a variable containing the function parameter.

You shouldn't push the student in the `else` block. That should only be done if you get through the entire loop without finding a match.

When logging that a student was added, you need to log the email, not the whole object.

The first `for` loop isn't using `this.students.length` as the limit.

When checking if the email is registered, you need to compare the `email` properties, not the whole object.

```js
class Student {
  constructor(name, email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
  }
}

class Bootcamp {
  constructor(name, level, students = []) {
    this.name = name;
    this.level = level;
    this.students = students;
  }
  registerStudent(studentToRegister) {
    if (!studentToRegister.name || !studentToRegister.email) {
      console.log("Invalid name or email");
      return false;
    }
    
    for (let i = 0; i < this.students.length; i++) {
      if (this.students[i].email == studentToRegister.email) {
        console.log('Email {studentToRegister.email} is already registered')
        return false;
      }
    }
    this.students.push(studentToRegister);
    console.log(`${studentToRegister.email} is now registered`)
    return true;
  }
}

testStudent = new Student('Bugs Bunny', 'bugs@bunny.com');
console.log(testStudent);
if (testStudent.name === 'Bugs Bunny' && testStudent.email === 'bugs@bunny.com') {
  console.log('TASK 1: PASS');
};

reactBootcamp = new Bootcamp("React", "Advanced");
console.log(reactBootcamp);
if (reactBootcamp.name === 'React' && reactBootcamp.level === 'Advanced' &&
  Array.isArray(reactBootcamp.students) && reactBootcamp.students.length === 0) {
  console.log('TASK 2: PASS');
}

const runTest = (bootcamp, student) => {
  const attemptOne = bootcamp.registerStudent(student);
  const attemptTwo = bootcamp.registerStudent(student);
  const attemptThree = bootcamp.registerStudent(new Student("Babs Bunny"));
  if (attemptOne && !attemptTwo && !attemptThree) {
    console.log("TASK 3: PASS");
  }
};

runTest(reactBootcamp, testStudent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because of this line

```
function studentToRegister(Student); {
```

the `;` is not supposed to go there, however there other issues with your code:

```
 for (let i = 0; i < this.students; i++) {
```

you are missing the length here.

```
 for (let j = 0; j < studentToRegister.length; j++) {
```

studentToRegister is not an array, you don't need another for, you should compare studentToRegister directly with the array of students, however the way you are trying to do it would not be correct either:

```
this.students[i] == studentToRegister
```

This will never return true. For Objects, `==` or `===` will return true only if the objects are the same instance. For content comparison you will need to compare the value manually in your case that would be email.

Comment: The instructions say they're just supposed to compare the email, not the whole object.

Comment: oops I will update it